# AFIncrementalStore to sync Core Data with REST API

Tags: ios, afincrementalstore

I was wondering if you have ever used AFIncrementalStore to sync between Core Data and a REST API? And if you so, it is a good approach to  use it without the Heroku Core Data Buildpack? I don't like dark magic :P

My Core Data model might not match exactly the REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIncrementalStore works fine with a simple REST API.

You may have to override the `representationForResponse` method for a fine match with your models but it should be all that is needed (except from the init part of course)

My advice: make an exact match between the API and your CoreData models and then use categories to generate the data the way you want them.

I'm currently doing an e-commerce app and my API send me products with an `expiration_date` which is a unix timestamp. I save as it is in CoreData and then I have a category on my NSManagedObject `Product` methods like `hoursRemaining`, `weeksFromNow` and so on for an easier display in the UI.

For the relationships, I'm not use those for automatic fetching with AFIncrementalStore so I can't say much.